# What's the purpose of 'taxonomies' parameter in register_post_type()?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

As mentioned in [`register_post_type()` Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type):

> **taxonomies**
>   ([*array*](http://codex.wordpress.org/How_to_Pass_Tag_Parameters#Array)) (*optional*) An array of registered taxonomies like `category` or `post_tag` that will be used with this post type. This can be used in lieu of calling [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) directly. Custom taxonomies still need to be registered with [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).
>   Default: no taxonomies

In my Custom Post Type (`product`) I'm also assigning two Custom Taxonomies with `register_taxonomy()` apart from the `register_post_type()`, and they are working fine. But there's a parameter in `register_post_type()` called `'taxonomies'` where it's said to mention all the taxonomies in an array, but even without this I'm achieving what it's meant to:

```
'taxonomies' => array( 'product_categories', 'product_tags' ),
```

So, I wonder what's the purpose of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be really honest here, that is a useless parameter when used with custom taxonomies, as custom taxonomies are already registed to a custom post type when they are registered. Using the `taxonomies` parameter, you are re-registering a custom taxonomy to the custom post type

As stated by the codex, the `taxonomies` parameter is used to register build in taxonomies to custom post types, as build in taxonomies are registered to the build in post type `post`.

Just to close of, if you register a taxonomy to a post type, set the `taxonomies` parameter and use `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`, you are doing the same job three times :-)

Comment: But makes perfect sense when registering CPT and adding _native_ taxonomies to them. :)

Comment: Can I point your attention to this part of Codex: **Custom taxonomies still need to be registered with `register_taxonomy()`.** Isn't it saying, **Still Need**? Isn't that mean, register once here and again there? It's just for clarification. I got your point, @Pieter.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I think we lost each other here :-) Custom taxonomies has to be registered with `register_taxonomy`. When doing so, you do need to asign a taxonomy to a post type, that is the second parameter when registering a custom taxonomy. This registers a custom taxonomy to the specific post type which is set in the second parameter of `register_taxonomy`. This takes care of everything, so you don't need to assign the `taxonomies` parameter when registering your post type